# What would the approx. min and max temperatures be for Snowball Earth with no atmosphere?

Tags: atmosphere, temperature, moon

I saw a similar previous question on this website about the temperature of the Earth with no atmosphere.  It sounds like if the Earth did lose its atmosphere we’d end up with either Snowball Earth or slushy Snowball Earth.

In that thread someone said the new average temperature of the Earth would be around 274.5K.

What I’d like to know is, if Earth lost it’s atmosphere, what would the new minimum and maximum temperatures be?

According to NASA currently the Earth has min of -88C and a max of 58C.

I am wondering if the Earth’s new min max would be similar to the moon: -233C min and 122C max.

Comment: https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-average-surface-temperature-of-the-earth-s-moon and no liquid water,water will sublimate in vacum(go directly from solid to gas).

Comment: As @trondhansen is suggesting with his comment, the Moon is very close to Earth & orbits Earth & can be considered an analog of what Earth would be like with without an atmosphere. A number of questions on SE Space Exploration dealing with lunar temperatures would also be applicable in this situation. Because there is no atmosphere, there is nothing to assist with heat loss via convection, only some heat loss via radiation. Consequently the surface can be hot, but centimeters above the surface would be cold. Shoes need to be insulated & even if one could, stones on the surface ...

Comment: ... would be too hot to touch with bare hands. See the answer to [*Astronauts of Apollo 11 facing extreme temperatures*](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48339/astronauts-of-apollo-11-facing-extreme-temperatures). Also, [*Vehicle liquids freeze on the Moon -- how has this problem been solved?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3468/vehicle-liquids-freeze-on-the-moon-how-has-this-problem-been-solved). [*What was the temperature of the Apollo 11 moon landing zone?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37366/what-was-the-temperature-of-the-apollo-11-moon-landing-zone).